# Load/power shedding for DIY power generation - how does it work?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, power-generation

I am putting together a simple DIY solar generation unit for an off grid cabin.

The cabin will "pull" (i.e. present) a variable load to the generator over a given time period.

Suppose I have this decision tree:

Apologies for the pseudocode, but I couldn't think of a more precise way to express the logic:

```
GEN_OUTPUT = generator_output()
CABIN_DEMAND_LOAD = cabin_demand()

if (GEN_OUTPUT != CABIN_DEMAND_LOAD) {

   if (GEN_OUTPUT < CABIN_DEMAND_LOAD) {
        call_backup_energy_reseve()
   }
   else {
       power_excess = GEN_OUTPUT - CABIN_DEMAND_LOAD

       // divert power excess into some other utility 
       // e.g. pumping water up a mountain or something ...
   }

}
```

I do not know much about power generation, but I think there must be some power configuration/circuitry that would allow automation of such power/load shedding logic?

If yes, is there an "off the shelf unit" one can buy - or better still, a schema that shows how to build such circuitry, using off the shelf components?

As an aside, it would be interesting if there could be some (HIGH LEVEL) explanation of how such a circuit works.

Comment: Some of the big Quality inverters do all of that automatically.

Comment: Great!  Thanks @SolarMike, at least, I know it can be done then. Would you be so kind as to point me to where I might find more details - with the aim of implementing my own custom circuitry - with unconventional load shedding logic?